# How do I target dynamic buttons created with different values jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button where when it's clicked I want the text to change to something else now the problem is that the button has the same class and everything as the other buttons on the page which will be generated dynamically since it's inside a foreach

How can I target only the button I click to change the text I have different values for each button can I use that?

```
<label class="more-information" value="{I call a data id with php}">
 <span class="more-info-text">Default text</span>
</label>
```

```
$('.more-information').on('click', function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      $(this).hasClass('active') ? $(".more-info-text").text('Default Text') : $(".more-info-text").text('Changed Text');

    });
```

This is what I'm currently using and it changes the text for all the buttons only when one button is clicked

Comment: You need to link the .more-info-text with the .more-information button.  You can do this numerous ways; the easiest is with DOM navigation if they're in the same parent or adjacent/siblings.  Or use `data-` attributes to link them.    If you provide html, a simple solution can be provided.

Comment: You can use something like `$(this).closest('.more').find('.more-info-text')` provided that both the text and the button are wrapped in an element that as `class="more"`. We really need to see the relevant HTML to point out the best way.

Comment: Could you please provide your html structure for `more-information` and `more-info-text`?

Comment: My bad I added the HTML structure as well(thought I did in the first place but oh well) also I kept saying button but it's actually an input that works like a button in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.more-information').on('click', function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      $(this).hasClass('active') ? $(this).find(".more-info-text").text('Default Text') : $(this).find(".more-info-text").text('Changed Text');

});
```

`$(this).find(".more-info-text")` will find the exact label for you on the click.